# About Lebesgue integral and Lebesgue measure-how to show if $f(x)$ is measurable+simple then $f(x+n)$ is.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(R,B(R),m)$ a Lebesgue measurable space on $R$. Let $f: R-> [0, \infty]$ a measurable function.
Denote $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n)$.

Show that if $\int_{R} F(x) dm$ is finite, then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Hint: first show that if $\phi$ is a measurable, simple function so $\phi_n(x)=\phi(x+n)$ is measurable and simple too, and $\int_R \phi dm=\int_R \phi_n dm$.

I said

$\int_R F(x) dm =\int_R \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n) dm$ =(by hint f(x+n) is measurable, and using a theory to change sum and $\int$) = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_R f(x+n) dm= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n) \int_R \chi_R dm= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n) m(R)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n) * \infty= F(x)* \infty$.

So, assuming that $\int_R F(x) dm$ is finite so $F(x)$ must be 0.

$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x+n)=0$ therefore $f(x+n)=0$ for every n
, since $f(x+n):R\to [0, \infty]$.

So, $\int_R f(x+n) dm =\int_R 0 dm= 0* \int_R \chi_R dm=0* \infty=0$.

Can you explain how to show the hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement $$\int_R f(x+n) \, dm = f(x+n) \int_R \chi_R \, dm$$ is egregiously wrong.

Instead you should use the translation invariance of the integral (which follows from the hint you were given) to write $$\int_R F(x) \, dm = \int_R \sum_n f(x+n) \, dm = \sum_n \int_R f(x+n) \, dm = \sum_n \int_R f(x) \, dm.$$ The last expression on the right is, by definition,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ n \int_R f(x) \, dm \right]$$ which is not finite if $0 < \int_R f(x) \, dm \le \infty$.

Comment: Note to the questioner: you need an application of the MCT to get the second equality in the second equation.

Comment: Can you explain how to prove the mentiined theory in the hint?

Comment: Can you explain how to prove the theory mentioned in the hint? @Umberto P.